# Generate xml using Dictionary<List<String>,List<string>>

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I am having a dictonary like this

```
  private readonly Dictionary<List<String>,List<string>> _optionsetlist=new Dictionary<List<string>, List<string>>();
```

adding list to dictionary like this

```
 List<string> optionset = new List<string> { _someText, _noteText, _optionsetLanguage, _optionsetselected };
_optionsetlist.a(optionset,optionset);
```

I want to geneate a xml using xdoucment

```
  var document = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
        new XElement("CheckItemDetail", new XAttribute("CheckItemTypeId", checkitem),
                                            new XAttribute("ButtonTypeId", buttonitem),
                                            new XElement("ToBechecked", _isSelected),
                                            from node in selectedItemsByTypeId select new XElement("Applicabilty",node.TypeId),
                                            from node in _selectedImageItem select new XElement("Images", node),
              //here dictinoary list values should come in place
                                   )
                      );
```

each list in dictionary consists of 4 values

sample output

```
    <CheckItemDetail CheckItemTypeId="C8C7D303-F9A0-4304-B865-9803034F4F4C"                      ButtonTypeId="25F6C9AA-5714-4646-944C-0C2325A74A88">
             <ToBeChecked>Y</ToBeChecked>
       <Applicability> 4,5,6 </Applicability>
      <Images>DDDDDDDD-F8B0-4A99-B699-F574E62A5425.jpg</Images>
     <DataDefinition>
          <DisplayOptions>
          <OptionSet Lang="GE" Default="true">
    <Designation>Motorraumverschalung inkl. Gummilippen</Designation>
       <Note>keine Beschädigungen </Note>
  </OptionSet>
</DisplayOptions>
 </DataDefinition>
 </CheckItemDetail>
```

this 4 details of above output should be filled with dictionaries

```
 <OptionSet Lang="GE" Default="true">
<Designation>Motorraumverschalung inkl. Gummilippen</Designation>
   <Note>keine Beschädigungen </Note>
```

Comment: A `List<string>` is a very peculiar choice for a Key. Didn't you just want a `Tuple<List<String>,List<string>>` ?

Comment: Please add a sample output to the question.

Comment: previously when the dictonary was there i used add items to dictonary like this _optionsetlist.add(optionset,optionset); how to add items in tuple

Comment: If you always add the same 2 items then a `List<List<string>>` would be enough.

Comment: Please check `DataDefinition>`. It neither opens nor closes correctly.

Comment: sorry that copy paste mistake corrected

Comment: OK, now can you match that up with a sample filling of the Dictionaries?